# Eingenvalues and Listplot take a long time optimize

Tags: plotting, matrix, eigenvalues

I try to calculate the following eigenvalues of a matrix of N=5 10^3 X5 10^3 and representing it using Listplot as follow

```
PL = Eigenvalues[{N[H], N[\[CapitalOmega]]}];
PL1 = Sort[PL];
data = Table[{Re[PL1[[x]]], Im[PL1[[x]]]}, {x, 500}];
interpolation = Interpolation[data];
ListPlot[interpolation] // AbsoluteTiming
```

but with N=3000 takes 5 minutes but for N=5000 crash it
 I do not how depurate it to avoid the mathematica crash
Thanks